# Is there a function callback available when Yii adds class error

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, transition

I am building some forms using Yii.
I'd like to polish the UX it offers on client side validation.  `'enableClientValidation'=>true,`
When a class error is added, I am using CSS transitions at the moment to animate how the error message is being displayed.

```
.new_events .bookingError {
    display: block !important;
    width: 243px;
    position: relative;
    margin: -36px 0px 0px 312px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: red;
    z-index: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.new_events .error .bookingError {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 312px;
}
```

FINE. But I really want a support IE on these animations, and the only way that comes to my mind is using somehow a callback after YII adds or toggles .error and then animate({},XX) it..
any light out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii uses plain jQuery to do this, the code you are looking for is in jquery.yiiactiveform.js, the updateInput function. The only solution I see at this point is writing your own javascript that adds for example an extra trigger call:

```
$(input).trigger('cssErrorClassAdded')
```

By default yii has a packages.php that points to all the different plugins (under /web/js/ in the framework). It's fairly easy to add a derived CClientScript file that includes your own php file and overrides the "yiiactiveform" package to point to your version.

Comment: wow, looks exactly what I was looking for..., now IE will be able to enjoy animations as well :). Tnx a lot